# Automatic test WPF App using NUnit

Tags: c#, wpf, testing, nunit

I am looking for an easy approach to test a (medium size) WPF application. Sort of what you'd do with BDD, but without the fancy specflow scripts, and instead of invoking mouse clicks we just want to interact with the `ViewModel` layer.

I refactored the code slightly so that I can start the application easier from a unit test. This is what I have now:

```
[TestFixture, RequiresSTA]
public class StartAndInitializeTests
{
    [Test]
    public void StartAndInitializeSystemControl()
    {
        var systemControl = new SystemControl((string) "302");

        // This line of code never gets executed because of App.Run() is not returning until
        // the application stops. 
        ViewModelContext.MachineControllerViewModel.InitMachine();
    }
}
```

Obviously the `InitMachine` method will never execute, because constructing `SystemControl` in the end results in the WPF app being started (`App.Run()`).

What is the best way around this? Handcraft some multi-threading framework which posts events to the UI thread and "mimics" user events? Or is there a somewhat proven framework that I should know about? Or should I have a completely different approach?

PS:

- We are not looking for an approach with specflow, because we don't really need external stakeholders to write tests, so we can and will manage this in NUnit directly
- We want to interact with ViewModels directly so that we don't have to bother with frameworks like `White`. Maybe we will go down that path in the future, but for starters we would like to keep it as simple as possible.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Generally you don't need to init the whole application when testing at a ViewModel level.  You should be using dependency injection which means if you instantiate a ViewModel any of its dependency will get injected appropriately in its constructor.  You can then perform your tests on the resulting ViewModel.  You may want to hook into ViewModel OnChangeNotify events and your Model to perform validation for your tests.

A simple example may be a property modifier on your ViewModel that modifies a property in the Model.  A example test may construct the ViewModel in question and hook into the Model underlying the ViewModel, modify the property on the ViewModel and check that the appropriate value is modified in the Model.